# Pass class as generic parameter Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics

im trying to instance a class passed as parameter to another, I have this in one file, ImportedClass.ts:

```
export default class ImportedClass {
  public constructor(something: any) {
  }
  public async exampleMethod() {
    return "hey";
  }
}
```

And this in another, InstanceClass.ts:

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
  new(something: any): T;
}

export default class InstanceClass <T> {
  private c: GenericInterface<T>;
  public constructor(c: T) {
  }
  async work() {
    const instanceTry = new this.c("hello");
    instanceTry.exampleMethod();
  }
}
```

And this in another, ClassCaller.ts: <--EDITED-->

```
import ImportedClass from './ImportedClass';
import ImportedClass from './InstanceClass';

const simulator = new InstanceClass <ImportedClass>(ImportedClass);
```

Then when I call it like this:

```
simulator.work();
```

It throw this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'exampleMethod' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T` must have a method named `exampleMethod` you must include this in the constraint for `T` on `Simulator` to be able to use it inside `Simulator`:

```
export class ImportedClass {
    public constructor(something: any) {
    }
    public async exampleMethod() {
        return "hey";
    }
}

interface GenericInterface<T> {
    new(something: any): T;
}

export class Simulator<T extends { exampleMethod(): Promise<string> }> {
    public constructor(private c: GenericInterface<T>) {
    }
    async work() {
        const instanceTry = new this.c("hello");
        await instanceTry.exampleMethod();
    }
}
const simulator = new Simulator(ImportedClass);
simulator.work()
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ImportedClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(something%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20async%20exampleMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22hey%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20GenericInterface%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(something%3A%20any)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Simulator%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20exampleMethod()%3A%20Promise%3Cstring%3E%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(private%20c%3A%20GenericInterface%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20async%20work()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20instanceTry%20%3D%20new%20this.c(%22hello%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20await%20instanceTry.exampleMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20simulator%20%3D%20new%20Simulator(ImportedClass)%3B%0D%0Asimulator.work())

There were other small issues that needed to be fixed to make the snippet above work, but that is the mai issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, <T extends { exampleMethod() }> i extended it but still get this error: TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof ImportedClass' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ exampleMethod(): any; }'.
  Property 'exampleMethod' is missing in type 'typeof ImportedClass'. 

Again thanks.

Comment: @user3314345 Your parameter to the constructor of `Simulator` was `T` you want it to be the constructor (`GenericInterface<T>`), check my sample code and the playground link.